# I have compilation error like Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory. Actual type: array; File:

Tags: overriding

```
use Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate\ItemPriceCalculator;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class Flatrate extends \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate
{
    protected $_code = 'flatrate';

    protected $_isFixed = true;

    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    protected $_rateMethodFactory;

    private $itemPriceCalculator;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate\ItemPriceCalculator $itemPriceCalculator,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->itemPriceCalculator = $itemPriceCalculator;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }
```

Comment: what change you want  at flatrate?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove your generated folder and give permission to the var and generated folder.

Remove your **generated** and **var** folder of Magento 2, run cache clean command, give permissions to **generate** and **var** folder then try again.